# Swagger UI adds a :80 to the request url when used with https with Traefik as reverse proxy

Tags: docker, swagger, microservices, reverse-proxy, traefik

My app is based on an microservice architecture all are running in docker containers with Traefik as a reverse proxy. when I try to request a microservice the request url appends :80 added (https://example.com:80/myService).

When I hit the Try it out! button I get an empty response body and 0 as response code.

If I request without traefik as a reverse proxy it works good for example http://hostname:8080/myService.

Can someone help me , Do I need to add some label for traefik at docker service level without modifying the code.
Also if there should be changes in swagger docs what are the changes that I should do?

[image]

Below is the docker stack file for reference.

```
    gateway-app:
    image: "gateway-app-image"
    environment:
        - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=
        - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=
        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=
        - SPRING_DATA_CASSANDRA_CONTACTPOINTS=
        - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=
        - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_HOST=
        - JHIPSTER_LOGGING_LOGSTASH_PORT=
        - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER-NAME=
        - SPRING_DATA_ELASTICSEARCH_CLUSTER_NODES=
        - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_BROKERS=
        - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_KAFKA_BINDER_ZK_NODES=zookeeper
        - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=
    networks:
        - traefik_proxy
    #ports:
     #   - 8080:8080

    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
            max-size: "100m" # The maximum size of the log before it is rolled
            max-file: "10"  # The maximum number of log files that can be present
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=8080"
        - "traefik.backend=gateway-app"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com"
        - "traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true"
        - "traefik.enable=true"
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

Comment: any updates anyone??